# Shade area chart above threshold - google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have looked at a variety of javascript charting libraries and decided to use [google charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart).  However I cannot figure out how to shade the top of my area chart (to indicate extreme values).  Its sort of like a chart intersection.

I created a [jsfiddle using Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/WWfEV/3).

`fillColor: {
    linearGradient: [0,103,0,104],
    stops: [
        [0, '#ff8888'],
        [1, '#aaaaff'],
    ]
}`

Has anyone else come across and solved this problem?

-- I tried to add color/gradient ranges but had no success.  Here is the [google chart jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAGsz/1/)